# How to create an asynchronous Edge Detector in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

I am new to VHDL. I would like to create an Edge Detector that works asynchronously (without use of clock signal).

I am using a simple schematic for this:

[image: edge detector]

In Quartus II (Altera/Intel) I have this code:

```
----
signal MyInput_Change : std_logic;
----
process (MyInput)   
begin

  MyInput_Change<= not(not (MyInput)) xor MyInput;  --edge detector
  if ( MyInput_Change = '1' ) then 
       --change state of FSM
  end if;
```

But this code doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Having used VHDL a long time ago only, is it possible that the compiler optimizes this away?

Comment: I thought so too.
If true, how can it be avoided?
Or is there another way to do it?

Comment: not(not (MyInput))` and `not(not (MyInput))` are expressions, operands of the overloaded operator `xor`. Expressions on the right hand side of a signal assignment are evaluated during execution. The two operands are evaluating the same same signal value (in simulation `not MyInput` does not imply a different named object). For detecting an edge you need to evaluate two separate signals. In synthesis the circuit in the image is generally not useful, inverters having wide delay margins and subject to being minimized or mapped away. Use sequential (clocked) logic for edge detection.

Comment: There is no way without using the clock?

Comment: With older technology logic cells had a much larger (and better defined) propagation delay, leading to constructs like LCELL in altera that allowed the deliberate insertion of a logic cell. But now, synth tools are very good at minimising circuits and delays are minimal (ps scale), so if you can get it to work the way you tried, the edge pulse would be very  short (100 of PS). Clocks can be 300Mhz+ in the more modern chips, giving very fine control of your edge pulse.

Comment: I'm using a Cyclone IV clocked at 16 MHz.
But, I don't think it's important, since it should be independent of it. 
At least I think so.

Comment: @BartFriederichs It's not just possible, it's all but guaranteed.

Comment: The complier usually optimizes/reduces all combinatorial functions. So the implied delay by chaining inverter is always optimized away and since the compilers are trimmed to optimize for clocked/registered based inputs the whole definiton is (not accounting for the intoduced delay and is simply) reduced to the mere logical funciton. If you want this code to synthesize properly you have to go for instantiating primitives (inverter/logic cells), based on the target hardware you are using.

Answer (score 2):

Declare signals:

```
signal I    : std_logic;         -- input
signal I_d  : std_logic := '0';  -- input delayed by 1 cycle
signal I_re : std_logic;         -- rising edge
signal I_fe : std_logic;         -- falling edge
signal I_ch : std_logic;         -- changed
```

Delay input signal:

```
I_d <= I when rising_edge(Clock);
```

Rising edge detection:

```
I_re <= not I_d and I;  -- old = 0, new = 1 => rising edge
```

Falling edge detection:

```
I_fe <= I_d and not I;  -- old = 1, new = 0 => falling edge
```

Edge / change detection:

```
I_ch <= I_d xor I;      -- old <> new       => changed
```

Comment: I have the same question: it is possible to do it without clock signal?

Comment: It is possible but (a) very difficult and (b) not at all recommended for the reasons already given. You'd only do it if there were no other possible way. Why do you want to do it without a clock?

Comment: Because I'm creating an asynchronous project, without a clock

Comment: Ok, I thought you could do it with an FPGA!

Answer (score 0):

I have had good luck with the attribute syn_keep (alternately keep depending on your synthesis tool).

```
signal A1, A2, A3, A4 : std_logic ;
attribute syn_keep : boolean ;
attribute synkeep of A1 : signal is true ;   
attribute synkeep of A2, A3, A4 : signal is true ;   -- should be able to group them, but if not do it as A1
. . . 

A1 <= not A ; 
A2 <= not A1 ; 
A3 <= not A2 ; 
A4 <= not A3 ; 

EdgePulse <= A xor A4 ;
```

This works for many things, but some synthesis tools - and even some place and route tools may be able to remove these.

Good Luck.   Let us know how it goes.

Comment: Ok, apparently it works fine (even the @Paebbels solution seems to work).

One thing I didn't think of is that when I turn on the circuit and when I turn it off, I get a status change.

I understand that I'm asking too much, but is it possible to avoid the detection of the change of state when I turn on and when I turn off the circuit?

Comment: If you can use a flipflop like @Paebbels suggested, then do so.   It will create a more stable solution.   If you want just the leading edge, then add an extra inverter to the path to X and use an "AND" gate rather than XOR.